# How do you combine columns based on shared values in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want combine the values of columns into a particular set of rows based on a shared row identifier. Here is a screenshot example of the data in Excel (left is current state and right is how I want it to turn out) [screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUERq.png) with the same information below (top is current state and bottom is how I want it to turn out.

| id | code | group | minutes | minutes 1 | minutes 2 | minutes 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1e | x222 | 1 | 4.5 | 4.5 | NA | NA |
| 1e | x124 | 1 | 4.5 | 4.5 | NA | NA |
| 1e | x143 | 2 | 6.7 | NA | 6.7 | NA |
| 1e | x123 | 2 | 6.7 | NA | 6.7 | NA |
| 1e | x123 | 2 | 6.7 | NA | 6.7 | NA |
| 1e | x143 | 3 | 8.9 | NA | NA | 8.9 |
| 1e | x123 | 3 | 8.9 | NA | NA | 8.9 |

| id | code | group | minutes 1 | minutes 2 | minutes 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1e | x222 | 1 | 4.5 | 6.7 | 8.9 |
| 1e | x124 | 1 | 4.5 | 6.7 | 8.9 |

I want to find a way to fill the NAs (for minutes 2 and 3) in the group 1 rows with the values for minutes 2 and 3 when they share an id (and drop the rows for groups 2 and 3). There may not necessarily be a group 2 or 3 for an id, and the number of codes vary for group 1.

I have tried reshape(), pivot_wider() (on the minutes column), and a few other things, but it hasn't worked for me yet. I feel like the solution is simple but for some reason I am stuck. Any advice would be appreciated! I would prefer to do this in dplyr/the tidyverse if possible.

Comment: Do you have `N/A` or `NA`.  Try `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("minutes"), ~ replace(.x, .x == "N/A", NA))) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(starts_with("minutes"), .direction = "downup") %>% ungroup`

Comment: It's actually NA. I got confused by the formatting (this is my first question). I'll fix that now!

Comment: @akrun This unfortunately did not change my data frame.

Comment: You need to assign back i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% ....` to update the  original object

Comment: I did. The NA part doesn't apply to my df because it's actually NA in R. The values for columns "minutes 2" and "minutes 3" are still NA for the Group 1 rows instead of having the minutes for groups 2 and 3. (Basically I want the last two columns in the first two rows to have the minutes for groups 2 and 3, and then drop the bottom 5 rows.)

Comment: Based on the data I copied from your post, it is giving the expected output as you showed.  If you could update your post with the `dput(head(yourdata, 10))` it would give the correct structure

Comment: It worked! My columns were not named the exact same (for anonymity reasons) but I was able to modify everything to work. Thank you! If you post this as an answer I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fill` from `tidyr` to replace the NAs with previous or next non-NAs after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1  %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(starts_with("minutes"), .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup
```